# Pandas - return all rows with identical values in one column and small differences in another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have some DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit':['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'pear', 'pear', 'pear', 'mango', 'mango', 'mango', 'peach', 'peach', 'peach', 'plum', 'plum', 'plum'],  
                   'region':[5,5,5,7,7,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                   'location':[75000,75000,75000,250,250,250,48897467,48897467,48897467,48897629,48897629,48897629,500000000,500000000,500000000], 
                   'unique':np.random.randint(100, size=15)})


    fruit   region  location    unique
0   apple   5   75000   51
1   apple   5   75000   1
2   apple   5   75000   44
3   pear    7   250 36
4   pear    7   250 86
5   pear    7   250 99
6   mango   2   48897467    40
7   mango   2   48897467    12
8   mango   2   48897467    33
9   peach   2   48897629    23
10  peach   2   48897629    85
11  peach   2   48897629    65
12  plum    2   500000000   46
13  plum    2   500000000   87
14  plum    2   500000000   42
```

I'd like to select all rows of different `'fruit'` with identical values in the `'region'` column and a difference of less than 1000 in the `'location'` column.

So, in this example, I'd like to return:

```
fruit   region  location    unique
6   mango   2   48897467    40
7   mango   2   48897467    12
8   mango   2   48897467    33
9   peach   2   48897629    23
10  peach   2   48897629    85
11  peach   2   48897629    65
```

I've tried something like:

```
df.groupby('region')['location'].diff()
```

But this isn't exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I am not very clear on the logic. Why is apple not in the output? for apple it is region 5 & since all location values are 75000, so the difference is zero. Same for pear as well.

Comment: Oops, I should have been more clear. I'm interested in different fruits, in the same region, with differences in location below 1000.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
a = df.groupby('region')['location'].transform(lambda x: x.max()-x.min())
b = df.groupby('region')['fruit'].transform('nunique')
df.loc[(a<=1000) & (b>1)]
```

**output**

```
fruit   region  location    unique
6   mango   2   9000    7
7   mango   2   9000    98
8   mango   2   9000    92
9   peach   2   8800    34
10  peach   2   8800    17
11  peach   2   8800    15
```

Comment: This works on my example, but as soon as I add another entry, it fails. Will update OP.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this as a new answer sicne the previous answer is usefull if someone wants the whole group instead of a portion of the group like you are wanting now.

For your latest need, you can do as below

```
def func(x):
    return (x - x.iloc[0])
a = df.groupby('region')['location'].apply(func)
b = df.groupby('region')['fruit'].transform('nunique')
df.loc[(a<=1000) & (b>1)]
```

This will only work of the column `location` is sorted ascendingly (make sure to sort the df by region & location before you start).

**output**

```
fruit   region  location    unique
6   mango   2   48897467    79
7   mango   2   48897467    62
8   mango   2   48897467    68
9   peach   2   48897629    71
10  peach   2   48897629    64
11  peach   2   48897629    69
```